# Sync from snapshot

Tags: mining, synchronization, bsc, full-node

I'm trying to do a sync on geth node from snap for 7 days, however that never ends. so That's filling up my SSD that has 3TB (currently It is using 76% from my SSD) and I think that's not normal

my hardware:
*-product: Intel Xeon Processor (Cascadelake)
*-cpu:16
*-memory: 32GiB
*-ssd:/dev/sda       3120795840 2245023604 728935280  76%     (3TB) only has snap sync

I have a download speed very good

[image]

I think isn't normal because I have a great hardware and a great download speed ... That's better than minimum requirements recommended from BSC for example they talk we need minimum 1TB but I have 3TB and that doesn't end the sync but that's using 76% from 3TB ...

I running that with:

```
/bsc/build/bin/geth --config ./config.toml --datadir ./mainnet
```

I'm using go1.17.3.linux and v1.1.5 hard fork release.

In first moment when I started the sync that was very speed and used more than 500mb

[image]

But currently that's very slow

[image]

someone has a answer for that?

Answer (score 1):

The official requirements for bsc are outdated. Many issues on the github repo have been opened about this.

Based on my personal experience, you need at least 12 cpu threads, 64 Gb of RAM, and most important of all, a fast and **dedicated** M.2 NVME SSD **attached directly to the machine** (2Tb is the minimum, but if you don't want to prune every week, 4Tb is required).

The last requirement means that you will not be able to sync on regular nvme cloud storage, such as aws EBS.

Comment: excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

My hardware's using 16 CPU, 32GiB and 3TB NVME

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).